# SwiftUI: Images in `List` causing memory leak

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, swiftui

I have the following SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {    
    let countries: [Country]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(countries) { country in
                    Section(header: Text(country.name.common)) {
                        ZStack {
                            Image(country.flagImageName)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: FlagView(country: country)) {
                                EmptyView()
                            }.hidden()
                        }
                        .listRowInsets(.init())
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Flags")
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

where `countries` is an array with a few hundred elements. Each `Country` has a `flagImageName`, which is the name of an SVG asset in the Assets folder.

When I interact with the view, specifically by scrolling it, and get to around 70% of the way down, the app either lags a lot (on the Simulator) or just crashes (on a device).

I'm not too sure what could be wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

After profiling, here are the results I obtained. Note the first spike of memory occurs after scrolling about 70% of the way through the list, and the next one happens at about 80%.

[image]

Here is the `Country` struct:

```swift
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct Country: Codable, Comparable, Identifiable {
    struct Name: Codable {
        let common: String
        let official: String
    }
    
    struct Currency: Codable {
        let name: String
        let symbol: String
    }
    
    let name: Name
    let tld: [String]
    let cca2: String
    let cca3: String
    let independent: Bool?
    let unMember: Bool?
    let currencies: [String : Currency]
    let capital: [String]
    let region: String
    let subregion: String?
    let languages: [String : String]
    let latlng: [Double]
    let borders: [String]
    let area: Double
    let flag: String
    
    var id: String {
        cca3
    }
    
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latlng[0], longitude: latlng[1])
    }
    
    var areaMeasurement: Measurement<UnitArea> {
        Measurement(value: area, unit: UnitArea.squareKilometers)
    }
    
    var flagImageName: String {
        cca2.lowercased()
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name.common < rhs.name.common
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Country, rhs: Country) -> Bool {
        lhs.name.common == rhs.name.common
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of the thing that you so-call memory leak?

Comment: Country?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato `Country` is a struct with several data fields. The `countries` array is populated from a JSON Data Asset

Comment: What's stopping you from showing the code for the Country struct?

Comment: @ElTomato sorry, just modified the description with the struct shown

Comment: And how big is the country image in pixels?

Comment: @ElTomato I first tried using SVGs, and now I am currently using 1280x640 PNGs

Comment: @ElTomato could you explain why?

Comment: How many images do you have in the list?  Do the math.

Comment: @ElTomato what would a better alternative be? since the images are used in their full-res in other places

Comment: I thought that your topic was concerned with the memory leak.  I don't see it.